# "Missing header/body separator" error with wp_remote_post()

Tags: php

I'm making a plugin that queries a local api, but this error shows on the plugin "Query Monitor".
Missing header/body separator

I'm calling the plugin from a page.

my code:

```
add_shortcode('wp-requester', function() {
 $url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/';
 $args = array('method'=>'post',
  'blocking'=>'false',
  'body'=>array());
 $post = wp_remote_post($url,$args);
}
```

edit: it's "false", not "'false'". I'll jump off a cliff.